# How can I Destructure or optimize the typescript code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, destructuring

In my typescript class I have `skip` function. In my `interface` I have mentioned `data coming from backend.`

On the `front end` I would like to `rename the backend variable` as shown below. There are multiple variables, `how can I optimize the code`?

I thought of using Destructuring concept but not sure how to use. I need help

```
 this.recordId = data?.data1;
   this.oldValue = data?.data2;
    this.newValue = data?.data3;
     ............// many more
```

ts function

```
skip(rec: ABC) {
  const {  data1, data2, data3 } = rec;

  this.records.skip({ data1, data2, data3}).subscribe(data => {
    this.recordId = data?.data1;         ---------------------------->Here
    this.oldValue = data?.data2;         ---------------------------->
    this.newValue = data?.data3;         ---------------------------->
     ............// many more

    this.processIncomingRecord(data);
  });
}
```

rec.ts

```
export interface ABC {
    data1: number;
    data2: number;
    data3: number;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure that you have any good options here. If you want them renamed and added as members to the class, I think the best way is how you've done it, although I admit it's painfully verbose.

Comment: I suppose you could use `Object.assign(this, {recordId: data1, oldValue: data2, newValue: data3})` but it doesn't save you that much typing

Comment: Thanks @mhodges. I could not find any better solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help. You can create a secondary "helper" map object (here `MapABCToDEF`) that maps the keys from `ABC` to what their frontend key names will be. Then, you can construct your frontend type (illustrated here as `DEF`) by using the "[mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)" feature (TS 4.1 and above).

```
interface ABC {
    data1: number;
    data2: number;
    data3: number;
}

const MapABCToDEF: {[Property in keyof ABC]: string} = {
    data1: 'recordId',
    data2: 'oldValue',
    data3: 'newValue'
}

type DEF = {
    [Property in keyof typeof MapABCToDEF as typeof MapABCToDEF[Property]]: ABC[Property];
}
```

[image]

This will help give you better type information is places you might want it. Ideally though you would just make your data names consistently the same across frontend and backend. I.e. don't use `data1` on the backend and `recordId` on the frontend, that will cause unnecessary complexity and confusion. Just pick one or the other and standardize it everywhere.

For the renaming itself, the map object `MapABCToDEF` can help you streamline the process of assigning key/values to `this` in a way that is consistent and type-enforced:

```
const abc: ABC = {
    data1: 100,
    data2: 200,
    data3: 300
}

// ...

const keys = Object.keys(abc) as Array<keyof typeof abc>;
keys.forEach(eaKey => {
    this[MapABCToDEF[eaKey]] = abc[eaKey];
});
```